# Jenkins Auto Deployment

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, continuous-deployment

Is there any way to make script in jenkins when this script be called or triggered jenkins automatically take last war of my project and deploy it in specific container
is differ from deploy to container which called after build as post-step

Comment: Yes you can do that.. Please share what you have tried and where you are getting issues.

Comment: i tried to deploy after every successful build, but i don't want this, i want it to deploy when i ask it to do that

Answer (score 0):

Yes, is possible, you just can `cp` from your build directory to your deployment directory.
In my case when I run my container I bind a volume mount with the `-v` parameter, when I build the jenkins job, it generate the package and I move to the remote docker volume.